# Custom Font in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to add a custom font but can't. I am getting error with below code, The font name is adding in the drop down but it's not changing...

my code is

config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
config.contentsCss = 'fonts.css';
config.font_names = 'Dekers/dekers_true' + config.font_names;
}
```

fonts.css:

```
@font-face {  
font-family: "dekers_true", serif;
src: url(fonts/Dekers_light.eot ); /* IE */  
src: local("Dekers"), url("fonts/Dekers_light.ttf") format("truetype"); /*non-IE*/  
}
```

Comment: why Dekers/ needs to added, is it necessary to wrote src: local("Dekers"), ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your custom CSS file must contain the basic styling for CKEditor body. CKEditor loads in the iframe with this CSS file only.

```
@font-face {  
    font-family: "dekers_true"; /* font name for the feature use*/
    src: url(fonts/Dekers_light.eot ); /* IE */  
    src: local("Dekers"), url("fonts/Dekers_light.ttf") format("truetype"); /*non-IE*/  
}
body {
    font: normal 13px/1.2em dekers_true, serif;
    color: #333;
}
p {
    font: normal 13px/1.2em dekers_true, serif;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em
}
...
```

And than add font declaration into your main site's CSS file too.

**Upd:** Alternative variant.
You can declare your custom styles, e.g.

```
config.stylesSet = [
    { name : 'Pretty font face', element : 'span', attributes : { 'class' : 'pretty_face' } },
    ... 
];
```

So will be applied class `.pretty_face` and than you can style it as you wish. If you want immediate preview in rte, you need to style this class in contentsCSS file too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. where i declare the custom styles, i tried in ckeditor\plugins\styles\styles\default.js but not getting the style in dropdown, can you give the small code for just add a font face and size in js. Please am new in ckeditor. strucking with bugs...Help me

Comment: Please read more about custom styles [here](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles)

Comment: Note: never change the core code as `ckeditor\plugins\styles\styles\default.js`, CKEditor config is very flexible. Also CKEditor has [jQuery adapter](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter), so you can call callback function after the editor will load.

Answer (score 6):

OR in config.js

```
config.font_names = 'Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
    'Comic Sans MS/Comic Sans MS, cursive;' +
    'Courier New/Courier New, Courier, monospace;' +
    'Georgia/Georgia, serif;' +
    'Lucida Sans Unicode/Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;' +
    'Tahoma/Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;' +
    'Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;' +
    'Trebuchet MS/Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
    'Verdana/Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;' + 
    **'Dekers/dekers_true';**
```

And then your CSS.
The above places it in Styles dropdown, not Fonts.

Comment: Awesome! This works for me. I added in my `main css` and ckeditor `contents.css` the font-face rule of my fonts, and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using hosted fonts and have a relatively simple use case, you can just add the stylesheets directly to `config.contentCss`:

`config.contentsCss = [ '/css/mysitestyles.css', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' ]`

Where the first file defines your styles (e.g. `.title { font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;`) and the second one is the remote stylesheet containing the font definitions.

The custom fonts should now appear in the drop-down menu and editor, providing you have defined the selectable styles in `config.styleSet`:

`config.styleSet = [ { 'name': 'Title', 'element': 'h1', 'attributes': { 'class': 'title' } ]`

I tested this using the CKEditor Django plugin, where the syntax is a little different to the above, but I can't see any reason why it wouldn't translate.